# What is the correct way to print programmatically duplex via libcups?

Tags: printing, c, cups, c++

This is my current approach, which does NOT work as expected. It just prints simplex in all three cases.

```
#include <cups/cups.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
cupsSetUser("myuser");
cups_dest_t *defaultP = cupsGetDest (NULL, NULL,num_dests,dests);

int jobid;
int num_options = 0;
cups_option_t *options=NULL;

//SIMPLEX
num_options = cupsAddOption ("Duplex", "None",num_options,&options);
jobid = cupsPrintFile(defaultP->name,"/home/myuser/work/TEST.ps","Test Print SIMPLEX",
                      defaultP->num_options,defaultP->options);
num_options = cupsRemoveOption("Duplex",num_options,&options);

//DUPLEX Long Edge
num_options = cupsAddOption ("Duplex", "DuplexNoTumble",num_options,&options);
jobid = cupsPrintFile(defaultP->name,"/home/myuser/work/TEST.ps","Test Print DUPLEX Long Edge ",
                      defaultP->num_options,defaultP->options);
num_options = cupsRemoveOption("Duplex",num_options,&options);

//DUPLEX Short Edge
num_options = cupsAddOption ("Duplex", "DuplexTumble",num_options,&options);
jobid = cupsPrintFile(defaultP->name,"/home/myuser/work/TEST.ps","Test Print DUPLEX Short Edge ",
                      defaultP->num_options,defaultP->options);
num_options = cupsRemoveOption("Duplex",num_options,&options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the correct way. There are wrong parameters in the second line of each cupsPrintFile(...). Should be `num_options, &options` instead of `defaultP->num_options,defaultP->options`.